# creating a timeline in Android

Tags: java, android

[image]

In Android, I want to create

- an interface that charts historical events on an X axis as shown.
- to have multiple Y axis items in which I'd display historical events through time for that item.
- yellow points would be clickable and display the historical event data.

  My question is, what would that be called? I'm not sure it's a Timeline, because I want to chart two items on the Y axis, and the Timelines I've seen don't have a Y axis. It doesn't look like the Time Charts I've seen either, if it were, I could use `aChartEngine`, right?

  So I need help identifying what this would be, and then some help on how to get started. For example, how to create the chart interface that would display yearly increments along the X axis starting from the first event up to the present day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started by looking at some of the available [graphing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android) for Android. Looking through and picking features those libraries provide that you can use will probably give you an idea of what to call your graph.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looking through those libraries it looks like what I want would be a line chart with time as the x-axis.

Comment: Your link is dead the so question seems to be deleted.